# Path exploration Page Title & Screen Name event count is not the same Engagement > Pages & Screens in GA4

Tags: google-analytics, single-page-application, google-tag-manager, analytics, google-analytics-4

A background: My application is a Single Page Application and is passing a custom page title that is generated from the URl and the Title is then passed using window.dataLayer.push function.

Now, when I user path exploration when I select a node Page Title and Screen Name the event count is very low for a screen for example in this image:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aq7U7.png)

For the same screen, when I look under Engagement > Pages and Screen > Page Title and Screen Name for the same page title the event count is much higher shown in this image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cz1qy.png)

Can anyone help me with this discrepancy? why is this happening? what can I do to fix this?

I haven't tried anything however this is the code below that we are using to push custom page title:

```
`/**
* Generate the custom dimention title based on the input URL
* @param {string} url 
* @return {string}
*/
const generateCustomDimensionTitle = (url: string): string => {
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(url);
    const type = urlParams.get(LOCATION_TYPE);
    const tab = urlParams.get(LOCATION_TAB);
    const section = urlParams.get(LOCATION_SECTION );
    const sectionItem = urlParams.get(LOCATION_SECTION_ITEM );
    const tabTitleStr = tab ? ` > ${tab}` : "";
    const title = section ? `${type} > ${section} > ${sectionItem}${tabTitleStr}` : `${type}${tabTitleStr}`;
 
return title;
};
 
/**
* Push URL data to google tag manager
*/
export function pushUrlDataToGtm(): void {
    if (window.dataLayer) {
        // google tag manager is loaded 
        const pageUrl = window.location.href;
        const pageTitle = generateCustomDimensionTitle(pageUrl);
 
        window.dataLayer.push({
            event: "virtualPageview",
            pageUrl,
            pageTitle,
        });
    }
}`
```